# Android ConstraintLayout - moving View fails

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

My goal is to dynamically create a grid of TextViews in a ConstraintLayout. I've seen *many* examples but there's an issue that I'm just not seeing. I've broken the task into two steps:

- creating the View
- positioning the View

I seem to have mastered the first but not the second. Usually I can modify a View's ConstraintSet if it is defined in XML and positioned at startup, but never when I've created it programmatically. When I create a View I'm careful to set an id, layout_width and layout_height. Method's I've tried for creating a new View:

- creating it and setting parameters from a new LayoutParameters object
- creating it and setting parameters from another View.
- inflating it from an XML template.

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/makeView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"
        android:text="Make View"
        android:onClick="makeView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/placeView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10sp"
        android:text="Place View"
        android:onClick="placeView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/makeView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/anchorView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
        android:text="View 00"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`MainActivity.java`

```
package com.example.textviewonthefly;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    final String TAG = "DEBUGME";
    final int START = ConstraintSet.START;
    final int END = ConstraintSet.END;
    final int TOP = ConstraintSet.TOP;

    int counter = 0;
    View anchorView;
    TextView nextView;
    ConstraintLayout  mainLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainLayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        anchorView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.anchorView);
    }

    public void makeView(View view) {
        nextView = new TextView(this);
        nextView.setLayoutParams(anchorView.getLayoutParams());
        int nextViewId = nextView.generateViewId();
        nextView.setId(nextViewId);
        int ViewCount = ++counter;
        String newName = String.format(Locale.US, "View %02d", ViewCount);
        nextView.setText(newName);
        this.mainLayout.addView(nextView);
    }

    public void placeView(View view) {
        ConstraintSet set = new ConstraintSet();
        set.clone(this.mainLayout);
        set.clear(nextView.getId());
        set.connect(nextView.getId(), TOP, anchorView.getId(), TOP);
        set.connect(nextView.getId(), START, anchorView.getId(), END);
        set.applyTo(this.mainLayout);
        anchorView = nextView;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You should create new layout params when creating the view and not sharing them with the anchorview. Make that change to see where it gets you.

Comment: I've tried `ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(WRAP_CONTENT,WRAP_CONTENT)`. Only change is that the new View appears in the top left. But the Place button still causes it to vanish. I think inflating an XML file is good practice & will be convenient for setting defaults. If I can make it work :-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

`clear(nextView.getId());` was too aggressive. I replaced that line with more specific directives:

```
clear(nextView.getId(), END);
clear(nextView.getId(), BOTTOM);
```

It's now working as intended, with a little revision my app creates a horizontal chain as I Add and Place:

```
[View 00][View 01][View 02]
```